# Convert textfile into dataframe, but text file structure is messy!( In Python)

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

So, I have a text file I tried `read_csv` but the file structure doesn't allow for `read_csv` to give desired output. I have been recommended to use `open()` function. instead, but have been unable to successfully apply it yet!.

Text file : [Textfile is from wikipedia of this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04BLm.png)

Now, I want a dataframe with two columns State and RegionName, but as they are vertically aligned I am not able to get desired output.

My Output: [Just one column is filled and rest is NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hHWs.png)

Desired output is of the form:

```
{('Alabama','Auburn'),('Alabama','Florence'),('Alabama','Jacksonville') so on}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all of your data is structured the same as in the photo provided, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["State", "RegionName"])

with open("example.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()
    lines = content.splitlines()
    state_split_str = "[edit]"
    region_split_str = "("
    for line in lines:
        if state_split_str in line:
            state = line.split(state_split_str)[0].strip()
        else:
            region = line.split(region_split_str)[0].strip()
            df = df.append({"State": state, "RegionName": region}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

The above would result in:

```
     State    RegionName
0  Alabama        Auburn
1  Alabama      Florence
2  Alabama  Jacksonville
3   Alaska     Fairbanks
```

This works because we know all schools in a state are preceded by a line containing the name of the state with "[edit]" beside it.  We simply check to see if "[edit]" exists in the string.  If it does, we split on "[edit]" and take everything to the left (the state name) via `[0]`.  For good measure we trim the new string of any leading/trailing whitespace.  This provides us with our State.  As we continue to iterate through each line, we know that if a line does not contain "[edit]" it is a school belonging to the current value of our "state" variable.

We then simply perform a similar split on the opening parenthesis of each string, and again take the first item of the list returned by split to obtain the RegionName, again trimming whitespace.  Since we now have both our State and RegionName values, we can append them to our dataframe.

Is this an ideal solution? Not exactly, because we're hardcoding values into our code to split on/column names for appending, but due to the format of your data, I'm not sure there is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works perfectly. I had issues with applying the seperator as I wasn't familiar.